# Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance stops bursting although CPU credit balance is positive

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am running a `python3` script on a Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Strangely, the CPU usage drops to baseline performance after some time **although** I still have enough CPU credits available to make the CPU burst. What causes this behavior and how can I avoid it?

**Edit 1**

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev  
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run  
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  3.0G  4.8G  39% /  
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/loop1       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/295  
/dev/loop2       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917  
/dev/loop3       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145  
/dev/loop4       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495  
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000  
/dev/loop5       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
```

Comment: Did you check the output of df -h, to ensure the availability of disk space?, ec2 instances has default 8GB root disk.

Comment: @sauravverma Thanks for your comment. I've edited the post to include the output of `df -h`. Disk space seems to be available and not causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that this phenomenon (i.e. CPU stops bursting although CPU credit is available) occurs if I've reached the available RAM for the EC2 instance. You can find the specs for different EC2 instances [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Comment: AWS itself doesn't control bursting based on memory usage so perhaps you are saying the python program itself is memory bound?

Comment: Well, the performance drop occurred when my python script required more RAM than was available to me on the EC2 instance. That's what I was trying to convey.

Comment: Perhaps that would happen on normal machines and non-bursting EC2 instances too? Either way you got to the bottom of it!

Comment: Of course it would. I admit, in hindsight the question is not the smartest, but since AWS does not show the RAM usage (as it does with the CPU utilization for example) it took a while until I figured what the issue was.